# Microsoft Graph API call recording

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, botframework

I have granted my Application permission to my Microsoft graph API and Admin have also consented to the permissions.
Permissions that I have added are:
[image: permission ss]

Now how do I make call to the API?
I haven't found any samples so far, how to make call to graph API with application permission.
Please help me out!!

Answer (score 0):

To create a call record, please see documentation here: [create call record](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/callrecords-callrecord-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). The documentation includes a sample requests ( http, Java, C#) with several scenarios. To create a call, please refer to this: [create call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-calls?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). To do this, you will first need to [register call bot for MS Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/calls-and-meetings/registering-calling-bot).

Let me know if this helps, and if you have further questions.